# Android Studio preview still displaying holo theme after switching to appcompat

Tags: android, android-studio

In a few seemingly random layouts, Android Studio is showing a holo preview even after switching to AppCompat.  I've tried restarting my computer, Android Studio, rebuilding, and clean building my project with no success.

Example layout:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Example"/>
```

I have checked my app's theme and there are no references to holo anywhere.

Is there some sort of cache in Android Studio I can clear?

Comment: You see holo theme in the emulator?

Comment: I don't think its called the emulator... its the "preview" section next to a layout when youre building the layout.

Comment: Yeah I know, sometimes the preview doesn't work. So I'm asking do you see the same in emulator too?

Comment: Gotchya :) nope, its correct in the emulator!

Comment: So I think you got the answer?

Comment: I was hoping to correct it in preview mode

Comment: I am not sure what's the problem but I think updating your Android Studio and all build tools might work.